# How do I use different drupal page templates?

Tags: drupal, templates

I have two page template files, one that is just 'page.tpl.php' and another for a subset of pages.

How can I apply this other template for only certain pages and the rest just default to page.tpl.php?

Thanks! I am on Drupal 6.

Answer (score 7):

In Drupal the templates follow so called "suggestions".

For pages, suggestions are built up using the url-path.

On page /foo/bar you can name your `page.tpl.php` as follows:

- page.tpl.php
- page-foo.tpl.php
- page-foo-bar.tpl.php

Drupal will look from most specific to least specific and pick the first one found. 
If page-foo-bar.tpl.php is found, it will use that for foo/bar if not found it will look on. If then it finds page-foo, it will use that.

page-foo.tpl.php will also be used for /foo/beserk foo/pirate and foo/parrot, unless off course, you create a page-foo-parrot.tpl.php.

The front-page has no path (obviously) but a suggestion for the fron-page does exist: `page-front.tpl.php` will be used only for the frontpage.

Comment: If you want to find out template suggestions for any piece of content, use http://drupal.org/project/devel_themer, wich adds a kind of firebug console that allows you to select any item on your page and will display lots of theme information for that. including all suggestions.

Comment: Isn't it double dash i.e. page--foo, rather than page-foo??

Answer (score 5):

In addition to Drupal's default suggestion system, you can implement template_preprocess_page in your theme and change the template suggestion array:

```
function my_theme_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
  if ($vars['some_var'] == 'some_value') {
    $vars['template_files'][] = "page-special";
  }
}
```

See [Working with template suggestions](http://drupal.org/node/223440).

You can also force the template file rather than adding a suggestion:

```
function my_theme_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
  if ($vars['some_var'] == 'some_value') {
    $vars['template_file'] = "page-special";
  }
}
```

Comment: The answer didn't work in drupal 7, using `$vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page__special';` worked, i.e., it loaded `page--special.tpl.php` present in my theme directory

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to check out the [Sections](http://drupal.org/project/sections) module, it allows selecting a separate theme for a set of pages. The selection of pages is the same as on the block display configuration page - Show on every page except the listed pages, Show on only the listed pages, Show if the following PHP code returns TRUE.

I used it on one of the sites I created, and it works great.

Comment: Though if you need to change your page.tpl.php depending on a page, then you need to use the other suggestions. Sorry if I don't help.